# REST API inside React.useEffect to run on each refersh of page

Tags: reactjs

I have put a RESTFUL API inside my react useeffect hook by using axios.get() method, I need this REST API function is fetched and run on each refresh of the page?

Actually when, I am testing my application it is jus running once and no longer it updates

My react useeffect is like below

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/is_logged_in/')
      .then(res =>{
        console.log(res);
        if (res.status!=200) {
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok');}
return res;})
.then(res=>{
  const value=res.data.res;
  set_is_logged_in(value);
}).
catch(error=>{
  console.log(error);
});});
```

I need this API to get re-run and fetched from the sever on each refresh of the page. How to achieve such functionality in reactjs?

Comment: What do you mean by refresh ? Hard refresh or just url state change ?

Comment: Each referesh of the page by browser..

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the concept:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your logic here which will run only one time when this component mounted
});

useEffect(() => {
  // your logic here which will run every time when the variable which is passed in dependency array change
}, []);  // Blank Dependency array

useEffect(() => {
      // your logic here which will run every time when the variable which is passed in dependency array change
    }, [variable1, variable2]);  // Dependency array
```

Explanation:

- Giving it an empty array acts like `componentDidMount` as in, it only
  runs once.
- Giving it no second argument acts as both `componentDidMount` and
  `componentDidUpdate`, as in it runs first on mount and then on every
  re-render.
- Giving it an array as second argument with any value inside, eg ,
  `[variable1]` will only execute the code inside your useEffect hook
  ONCE on mount, as well as whenever that particular variable
  (variable1) changes.

[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: What do you mean from varibale? in my case it would be ''const value'' inside useeffect hook?

Comment: On every refresh if there is some variable whose value is changed then pass that variable in dependency array

Comment: I am new to react but I can't get your words what is a variable?

Comment: Have your checked the reference link ?

Comment: Yes, that would be my state variable but is there any general event in react  so I can fetch my API and change my state variable frequently on each reactjs event?

Comment: If possible create a jsfiddle of your code and share the link so that I can check what exact issue you are facing ?